# Sending messages between producer and consumer does not work

Tags: java, spring, websocket

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/producer")
public class ProducerController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    private  UserAuditRepository userAuditRepository;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerController.class);


    @Autowired
    public ProducerController(UserAuditRepository userAuditRepository) {
        this.userAuditRepository = userAuditRepository;
    }
    @PostMapping("/send-message/{userId}")
    public ModelAndView sendMessageToUser(@PathVariable String userId) {
        logger.info("Sending message to user: {}", userId);

        // Проверяем существование пользователя
        Optional<UserAudit> existingUser = userAuditRepository.findByUserId(userId);
        UserAudit userAudit = existingUser.orElseGet(() -> {
            UserAudit newUser = new UserAudit();
            newUser.setUserId(userId);
            return newUser;
        });

        MessageDto messageDto = new MessageDto(true, "gold", 123, "Hello World", userId);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userId, "/topic/messages", messageDto);

        // После отправки сообщения, перенаправляем пользователя на страницу user-audit
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/consumersocket/api/consumer/user-audit", true));

    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/consumer")
public class ConsumerController {

    @Autowired
    private UserAuditRepository userAuditRepository;

    @MessageMapping("/messages")
    @SendToUser("/topic/messages")
    public void processMessageFromProducer(@Payload MessageDto messageDto, Principal principal) {
        UserAudit userAudit = new UserAudit();
        userAudit.setUserId(messageDto.getUserId()); // Извлекаем userId из сообщения
        userAudit.setIsActive(messageDto.isActive());
        userAudit.setColor(messageDto.getColor());
        userAudit.setNumber(messageDto.getNumber());
        userAudit.setMessage(messageDto.getMessage());
        userAuditRepository.save(userAudit);
    }

    @GetMapping("/user-audit")
    public String getUserAudit(Principal principal, Model model) {
        Optional<UserAudit> userAuditOptional = userAuditRepository.findByUserId(principal.getName());

        if (userAuditOptional.isPresent()) {
            UserAudit userAudit = userAuditOptional.get();
            model.addAttribute("userAuditList", Collections.singletonList(userAudit));
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("userAuditList", Collections.emptyList());
        }

        return "user-audit";
    }
}
```

Both microservices are started, after entering the password, the message from producer to consumer does not reach, the message is not written to the database.
http://localhost:8080/producersocket/api/producer/send-message
server.servlet.context-path=/producersocket
http://localhost:8081/consumersocket/api/consumer/user-audit

The url was written differently, nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the value of the annotation in the `processMessageFromProducer` method is incorrect.

When `convertAndSendToUser` is triggered in producer, the message is sent to `/user/{sessionId}/topic/messages` channel. However, the consumer is listening to `/messages` channel.

Also, `@SendToUser` will send the method result as a message to the specified channel. However, as `processMessageFromProducer` is a void method, I think it will not work correctly.

You may try the following changes:

```
@MessageMapping("/user/{sessionId}/topic/messages")
public void processMessageFromProducer(String sessionId, @Payload MessageDto messageDto) {
    ...
}
```